# Erro com while em joption pane: loop

Tags: java, string, while, joptionpane

Estou tendo um problema sério com o while no seguinte algoritmo: Tem-se um conjunto de dados contendo a altura e o sexo (masculino, feminino) de 50 pessoas. Fazer um algoritmo que calcule e escreva:

1 - a maior e a menor altura do grupo;

2 - a media de altura das mulheres;

3 - numero de homens.

---

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Problema1122 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float altura = 0, maiorAltura = 0, menorAltura = 0, mediaAlturaM = 0;
        int quantHomens = 0, quantMulheres = 0;
        String sexo = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            **do {
                sexo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o sexo da " + (i + 1) + " pessoa (F ou M): ");
            } while (!sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("f") || !sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("m"));**

            altura = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a altura da " + (1 + i) + " pessoa: "));

            if (sexo == "f") {
                quantMulheres += 1;
                mediaAlturaM += altura;

            } else {
                quantHomens += 1;
            }
            if (menorAltura > altura || menorAltura == 0) {
                menorAltura = altura;
            } else if (maiorAltura < altura) {
                maiorAltura = altura;
            }

        }
        mediaAlturaM = mediaAlturaM / quantMulheres;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "A maior altura é: " + maiorAltura + "\n e a menor altura é: " + menorAltura
                        + ".\n A média de altura das mulheres é: " + mediaAlturaM + "\n e a quantidade de homens é: "
                        + quantHomens);
    }
}
```

Coloquei o algoritmo todo para terem um ideia geral caso necessário, mas o problema é que ao escolher o sexo, mesmo colocando F ou M sempre continua pedindo o sexo da primeiro pessoa (entra em loop). Tentei comparando string com  ==, depois descobri que deve ser usar o equals, tentei também, tentei mudar a lógica usando | ou ||...mas nada da certo!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está verificando se

```
sexo difere de F ou sexo difere de M
```

Testes de mesa:

```
true ou false  = true // Input = M
false ou true  = true // Input = F
true ou true = true //Input != F e M
```

Esse é o motivo de sempre estar em loop. A lógica correta seria:

```
sexo difere de F e sexo difere de M
```

Utilizando os mesmos testes de mesa:

```
true e false = false // Input = M
false e true = false // Input = F
true ou true = true //Input != F e M
```